# how to restrict user to select date of birth who is under 21 years in android

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-calendar, android-datepicker

I am using DatePickerDialog to select the users date of birth.How to restrict user to select date of birth who is under 21 years from current date.

**Eg:the users date of birth after 14/6/1996 should be restricted from selecting**

This is my code,

```
 Date today = new Date();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(today);
        c.add( Calendar.YEAR, -21 );
        minDate= c.getTime().getTime();
        Log.v(Constants.TAG, "selecteddsdf " + minDate);

   public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {

    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(v.getContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {


            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDate);

            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            txtDOB.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            uDOB = dateFormatter2.format(newDate.getTime());
            Log.e(Constants.TAG, "onDateSet: UserDob: " + uDOB);
        }

    }, year, month, date);

    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below method for that

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(minDate.getTime());
```

setup for minDate

```
 Date minDate = null;
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
 try 
 {
         minDate = sdf.parse("31/12/1996");
 } 
 catch (ParseException e) 
 {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: what value i need to give for "your_min_date_long_value". because date will be incremented everyday

Comment: still i can select the date after 14/6/1996

Comment: you have to substact 21 years for that

Comment: @ Vishva Dave: I did bro.. but same thing i can select any days including future days

Comment: @ Vishva Dave:  Did you find where i am going wrong?

Comment: @abhinayg sorry for late replay because i have some work so , and check my updated answer i think it will help you out.

Comment: Same issue bro.. Did u check with the date picker.. I think i am going wrong somewhere in datepicker

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(maxDate.getTimeInMillis());
```