# how can I implement calendar where the age must be above 18

Tags: android

```
private void findViewsById() {
    fromDateEtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dobET);
    fromDateEtxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    fromDateEtxt.requestFocus();
}

private void setDateTimeField() {
    fromDateEtxt.setOnClickListener(this);
    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar dob = Calendar.getInstance();
            dob.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            fromDateEtxt.setText(dateFormatter.format(dob.getTime()));

            Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
            dob.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            int age = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dob.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            Integer ageInt = new Integer(age);
            String ageS = ageInt.toString();
            if(age >= 18) {
                fromDateEtxt.setText(dateFormatter.format(dob.getTime()));
                fromDateEtxt.setError(null);
            }
            else {
                fromDateEtxt.setText("");
                fromDateEtxt.setError("Age must be above 18 years.");
            }
        }

    }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

}
```

In the example we want the calendar will show only 18 plus years for date of birth. I used fromDateEtxt.setError("Age must be above 18 years.") for if the user is less then 18 years.

Comment: check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/44545781/8164071

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict user using setMaxDate()

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -18);
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, null, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(cal.getTime().getTime());
dpd.show();
```

Comment: Sir I used this code but when I click on edit text it is showing till 2017 but when I close it and re-open again it works proper

Comment: can you post what you have implemented?

Comment: I am trying to post what i have implemented but it's too long to post here. but I am sending some part of them.

Comment: private void setDateTimeField() {
        fromDateEtxt.setOnClickListener(this);
        dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy",Locale.US);
        dob = Calendar.getInstance();
        fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,   new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

Comment: dob.add(Calendar.YEAR, -18);
                fromDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(dob.getTime().getTime());
                dob.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                fromDateEtxt.setText(dateFormatter.format(dob.getTime()));
                dob.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    fromDateEtxt.setText(dateFormatter.format(dob.getTime()));
            }
        }, dob.get(Calendar.YEAR), dob.get(Calendar.MONTH), dob.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }

Comment: please check this code which I sent on above two comments.

Comment: sir is used this dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(cal.getTime().getTime()); but its not working

Answer (score 0):

```
private void setDateTimeField() {
    fromDateEtxt.setOnClickListener(this);
    dob = Calendar.getInstance();
    fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,   new 
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, 
int dayOfMonth) {

            dob.add(Calendar.YEAR, -18);

fromDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(dob.getTime().getTime());
            dob.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            fromDateEtxt.setText(dateFormatter.format(dob.getTime()));
            dob.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                fromDateEtxt.setText(dateFormatter.format(dob.getTime()));
        }
    }, dob.get(Calendar.YEAR), dob.get(Calendar.MONTH),
```

dob.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
       }